# Turn off laptop moniter display forever

Tags: multiple-monitors, lcd

I have a Dell e6400 laptop with a damaged LCD. I want to switch the display of the laptop to a external monitor forever. My problem is if I connect an external monitor, that starts to display the screen only after the OS boots up. In newer Windows I have to manually do the switch (I use a torch for changing the display seeing in the damaged monitor). I can not install a new OS because of this as the monitor can load only after OS start. Also I can't go into BIOS settings. Is there a way I can permanently disable the laptop LCD?

Comment: Or maybe replace the backlighting and fix the laptop? ;)

Answer (score 0):

If there's a setting to always use an external monitor in the BIOS then it might work, but since you can't get to the BIOS now...

You could unplug the laptop's built-in monitor cable (almost always a flat ribbon-type) and using some converter, connect your external monitor to your laptop. It would then see the external monitor as the built-in monitor and *should* work as you'd like.

I've seen a few different types of monitor adapters, they vary on the type of internal connection and the type of external monitor connection, so I couldn't guess which one would work for you. Contacting some sellers or manufacturers of such devices and asking them what would work for your specific laptop & monitor would probably be best, and that would give you an easy concrete reason for a return in case it doesn't work too.